# MS Access error inserting QuickBooks InvoiceLine for single invoice

Tags: sql, ms-access, csv, odbc, quickbooks

I am using QODBC connector to enter and alter data in my QuickBooks Company File.

I am trying to create a MS Access script to pull all data out of a csv file and add the csv data as invoices in the table.

I can successfully add new invoices using this code:

```
    INSERT INTO InvoiceLine (CustomerRefListID, RefNumber, InvoiceLineItemRefListID, InvoiceLineDesc, InvoiceLineQuantity, InvoiceLineRate, InvoiceLineSalesTaxCodeRefListID) VALUES ('80000078-1311176211','99990','800007D6-1369617126','Description', 2.00, 9.09, '80000009-1311174909')
```

I am extremely interested in adding to the field TxnNumber as this seems to be the field that allows for multiple items to be added to the same invoice (ie. if 4 entries in InvoiceLine with same TxnNumber and RefNumber, they will show as one invoice.

My attempt at the query is below.

```
INSERT INTO InvoiceLine (CustomerRefListID, TxnNumber, RefNumber, InvoiceLineItemRefListID, InvoiceLineDesc, InvoiceLineQuantity, InvoiceLineRate, InvoiceLineSalesTaxCodeRefListID) VALUES ('80000078-1311176211', '8177', '99990','800007D6-1369617126','Description', 2.00, 9.09, '80000009-1311174909')
```

Below in the error message that I am seeing:

```
ODBC--insert on a linked table 'InvoiceLine' failed.
[QODBC] Field not allowed in insert. (#10046)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TxnNumber` column has nothing to do with tying things back to an Invoice in the QODBC schema.

The field you want is `TxnID`, not `TxnNumber`. Use `TxnID` instead.

Here's a link to the QODBC docs showing the relations:

- http://doc.qodbc.com/qodbc/20/tables/table_relations_us1571.html?trelations_id=38&tn_us=TRUE

Comment: If I could clone you and borrow your brain, I would pay you with my love. You sir are a knight and a gentleman.

Comment: Hahaha, that comment made my night! Glad I could help!

Comment: Dumb question, how would I go about using the current timestamp in the TxnID field?

Comment: More detailed examples: http://www.qdeveloper.com.au/forum.php?homeinclude=topicdetails&forum_id=1where&category_id=3&post_id=124

Comment: Thanks mate. Should've known Tom would have posted something hahah.

Comment: Hi dan. Can you post now an example showing how you added the four records to the same invoice. It will help other people alot.